# Creating collection of pdfs with wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wicked-pdf

I have problem collection of pdfs file and save it to file. I create this for show action so when I clink the link it generate pdf and store them in public folder:

```
def show
    add_breadcrumb "Inovice details"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => "file_name", :save_to_file => Rails.root.join('public', "Invoice no. #{@invoice.format_id}.pdf")
      end
      format.csv {send_data Invoice.where(id: @invoice.id).to_csv,
        filename: "Invoice no. #{@invoice.format_id}.csv"}
    end
  end
```

Now I want to create the same functionality but for collection of objects. For examples I have 10 invoices and I want for all of them generate pdf and save it to public folder. I was trying something like that:

```
def index
      @invoices = @company.invoices
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      format.csv { send_data @invoices.to_csv }
      format.pdf do
        @invoices.each do |invoice|
          render :pdf => "file_name", :save_to_file => Rails.root.join('public', "Invoice no. #{invoice.format_id}.pdf")
        end
      end
    end
    authorize @invoices
  end
```

But it didnt work. I have no ideas how to solve this problem. I will be grateful for every help.

Answer (score 3):

You can not send multiple PDF's in the same request.

I think a best solution is generate the PDF's in a background job ( https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/wiki/Background-PDF-creation-via-delayed_job-gem ) and present an HTML page with links to all you PDF's.

If that doesn't work for you, you can merge all the content in a big PDF file.